# CREATE VIEW with IF and ERROR

Tags: mysql, if-statement, create-view

```
CREATE VIEW nextClass AS
SELECT date,id
FROM class
WHERE date >= CURDATE()
AND IF (
    date < CURDATE(),
    ERROR_MESSAGE('You cannot update previous classs'),
    CLOSE()
    )
```

Can someone help with the CREATE VIEW statement in SQL.
I need to show all future classes and reject attempts to update previous classes. 
I have a syntax error in this code.

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: where I have added CLOSE(), it says the error is on that line, if I take that out it is on the last ' ) '

Comment: I do not know what error_message() or close() functions do, but I suspect that they have something to do with the error message! This logic seems to be closer to what you would expect from a stored procedure, not from a view. View is supposed to return data.

Comment: Do you know what to use instead of error_message() and close(), like reject update for previous date + show message

Comment: Again, such tasks are for stored procedures and **not** for views. Views do not check previous updates. Views are basically compiled select statements only. The alternative to stored procedures is to implement this logic in the application itself.

Comment: ''Produce a view that returns the classes in the future and rejects any attempt to insert or update previous classes'' Thats what I have to do if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls refer to mysql's documentation on [creating views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html):

> The WITH CHECK OPTION clause can be given for an updatable view to
>   prevent inserts or updates to rows except those for which the WHERE
>   clause in the select_statement is true.

So, all you need to do is to add `WITH CHECK OPTION` to the end of the `CREATE VIEW` statement.